# Remove everything after certain character and length

Tags: bash, shell

I want to remove all  text after certian format.

```
<JOB APPLICATION="Daily" SUB_APPLICATION="Y#D5#4#M2F" JOBNAME="MLETTXXD-NONR_005" DESCRIPTION="" CREATED_BY="vpma" RUN_AS="ctmagt" CRITICAL="0" TASKTYPE="Dummy" NODEID="OPENFRAME"  %%ENVIRONMENT MLETTXXD %%ORDERID %%RUNCOUNT %%JCL_STEP" CONFIRM="0" RETRO="0" MAXRERUN="0" AUTOARCH="1" MAXDAYS="0" MAXRUNS="0"  TIMETO="&gt;" JAN="1" FEB="1" MAR="1" 
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-A#D5#4#M2F-STRTDAYA-001-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-PS#P#D3#SU2SA@E-TIME0000-098-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
```

Delete all string before and after `JOBNAME="..."`

Output should be

```
JOBNAME="MLETTXXD-NONR_005"
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-A#D5#4#M2F-STRTDAYA-001-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-PS#P#D3#SU2SA@E-TIME0000-098-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
```

I tried below but not happening for second `awk` condition.

```
awk '/JOBNAME=/{print $4} | /INCOND/{print $2}' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to do this yourself? If so, can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I used awk '/JOBNAME=/{print $4} | /INCOND/{print $2}'  inputfile.txt

Comment: Please add the attempt to your question and not as a comment.

Comment: can `JOBNAME="..."` show up more than once in a given line?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed s'/.*\(JOBNAME[^ ]*\).*/\1/' input_file
JOBNAME="MLETTXXD-NONR_005"
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-A#D5#4#M2F-STRTDAYA-001-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-PS#P#D3#SU2SA@E-TIME0000-098-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix to OP's current `awk` code:

```
$ awk '/JOBNAME=/{$0=$4}1' inputfile.txt
JOBNAME="MLETTXXD-NONR_005"
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-A#D5#4#M2F-STRTDAYA-001-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-PS#P#D3#SU2SA@E-TIME0000-098-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
```

**NOTES:**

- `$0=$4` says to replace the current line with the contents of the 4th field
- assumes OP's `/INCOND/` pattern match is an attempt to print the rest of the lines of input hence ...
- the standalone `1` says to print the current line

This has a few limitations:

- assumes the `JOBNAME="..."` string is *always* in the 4th space-delimited field of a line
- does not take into consideration multiple instances of the string in a single line
- assumes the string does not contain any white space

Addressing the limitations ...

First we'll add a new line to the input:

```
$ cat inputfile.txt
<JOB APPLICATION="Daily" SUB_APPLICATION="Y#D5#4#M2F" JOBNAME="MLETTXXD-NONR_005" DESCRIPTION="" CREATED_BY="vpma" RUN_AS="ctmagt" CRITICAL="0" TASKTYPE="Dummy" NODEID="OPENFRAME"  %%ENVIRONMENT MLETTXXD %%ORDERID %%RUNCOUNT %%JCL_STEP" CONFIRM="0" RETRO="0" MAXRERUN="0" AUTOARCH="1" MAXDAYS="0" MAXRUNS="0"  TIMETO="&gt;" JAN="1" FEB="1" MAR="1"
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-A#D5#4#M2F-STRTDAYA-001-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-PS#P#D3#SU2SA@E-TIME0000-098-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
<JOB APPLICATION="Daily" JOBNAME="JOBNAME # 1" DESCRIPTION="" JOBNAME="Another Job" CREATED_BY="vpma"
```

A `GNU awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FPAT="\\<JOBNAME=\"[^\"]*\"" }    # define field pattern as JOBNAME="..."
NF    { pfx=""                            # if we have a FPAT match then NF>0
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {             # loop through our FPAT matches
            printf "%s%s",pfx,$i          # print each FPAT match to stdout
            pfx=OFS
        }
        print ""                          # terminate the line of FPAT matches
        next                              # go to next line of input
      }
1                                         # print all lines that do not have a FPAT match
' inputfile.txt
```

**NOTE:**

- `GNU awk` is needed for `FPAT` support (this allows us to define the format of the field; this replaces the use of `FS` which defines the format of the field *delimiter*)
- standalone `1` assumes OP wants to print all other lines of input that don't have a match to the string `JOBNAME="..."` (otherwise OP should update the sample input to contain lines that should not be printed)

This generates:

```
JOBNAME="MLETTXXD-NONR_005"
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-A#D5#4#M2F-STRTDAYA-001-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
                <INCOND NAME="PROD-PS#P#D3#SU2SA@E-TIME0000-098-OK" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="A" />
JOBNAME="JOBNAME # 1" JOBNAME="Another Job"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{ .* ( JOBNAME="[^"]*" ) .* }{$1}x;' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

The regex uses these modifiers:
`/x` : Ignore whitespace and comments, for readability.

`s{ .* ( JOBNAME="[^"]*" ) .* }{$1};` : Replace this pattern: `.*` - any character repeater 0 or more times, followed by `JOBNAME="[^"]*"`, which has `[^"]*` - any character *except* `"`, repeated 0 or more times, followed by `.*`. Replace this pattern with `$1`: the first capture group, that is whatever was matched inside the parentheses.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)